# Don't know what to write in my message variable?

Tags: php, html

I am a PHP noob, so i don't know what to write in my message variable. I need my data from the form to be sent to the email. I got a textarea, 2 inputs (name, email). Want the text from input to be sent to my email. Here code i have:

```
<?
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="") && (isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){ 
    $to = 'rayetzkiillya@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Обратный звонок';
    $message;
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@example.com>\r\n";
      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
?>

 <form action="send.php" class="postcard" method="post">
 <span>Your message:</span>
 <textarea type="text" value="" required></textarea>
 <div id="stripe1"></div>
 <div id="stripe2"></div>
 <img src="./images/Seal_of_the_United_States_Department_of_the_Post_Office.svg. png" alt="Oops" id="seal" />
 <img src="./images/stamp.jpg" alt="Stamp" id="stamp" />
 <div class="inputs">
 <div class="inputs" id="input1"><label for="to" type="text" id="to">to: </label> <input type="text" value="     Me" readonly><div id="stripe3"></div></div>
 <div class="inputs" id="input2"><label for="from" type="text" id="from">from: </label> <input type="text" id="input2"><div id="stripe3"></div></div>
 <div class="inputs" id="input3"><label for="email" type="text" id="email">email: </label> <input type="text" id="input3"><div id="stripe3"></div></div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="send_button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: btw, you can replace `if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")` with just `if(!empty($_POST['name']!=""))` it does the same thing and uses less code. Same for the other one.

Comment: Add `trim` to your validation when using `empty`.

Comment: You really should have read the (right) tutorials.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `if(!empty($_POST['name']!=""))` seems peculiar!

Comment: @RamRaider I just noticed that. xD

Comment: @RamRaider *duh!!!!!* lol sorry I meant `if(!empty($_POST['name']))` I forgot to remove the `!=''`. *My bad*.

Comment: I thought "that @Fred-ii-, he must have a trick up his sleeve with that notation" so I tried it too :(

Comment: @RamRaider hahaha, I only wish. "Peculiar" though however, does make a few heads turn though ;-) made you L@@K *haha!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your message an HTML string, or just plain text.
For plain text, you can do something like

```
$message .= "name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n";
$message .= "Message: ".$_POST["theMessage"];
```

However you need to name your inputs in the HTML as well,
so

```
<input type="text" id="input2" name="name">
<textarea type="text" value="" required name="theMessage"></textarea>
```

Or similar.

For the from address, you have to use change your header line
change

```
$headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@example.com>\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers .= "From: ".$_POST["name"]." <".$_POST["from"].">\r\n";
```

And obviously name your input accordingly:

```
<input type="text" id="input3" name="from">
```

Also, as suggested by others, you should be sanitizing/validating these values before using them.

Comment: I want this message to be taken from a textarea value

Comment: I've added in changes for that.  You need to name the textarea, then treat it like any other variable in PHP.

Comment: No validation or sanitization, really? You must really trust your users.

Comment: Thx a lot, and how can i put a client email?

Comment: I'm using a simple explanation of how to get the variables through, but yes you should validate and escape the strings if they are being submitted via a web form for security.

Comment: @Script47, you are a clever man, but i have just said that i am a PHP noob :)

Comment: @SilicaGel, how to put clients email, so that i got a message from his addres to my inbox?

Comment: I've revised the answer to include the email address